# Navmii Map installation problem

Tags: maps

I have a Samsung Galaxy Core Prime 8GB, and I tried to install Navmii maps. But, when installing the UK & RROI maps, it has stalled at 91% and consequently failed twice.

I have tried to contact Navmii support, but no good.

Any suggestion?